# Does Amplified Rage stack with Normal Rage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

As the Feat suggests, Amplified Rage should stack with normal rage.
Is this correct? So I would get +8 in STR and CON when I'm adjacent to a raging ally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

According to [Amplified Rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/amplified-rage-teamwork)

> Whenever you are raging and adjacent to a raging ally who also has this feat or flanking the same opponent as a raging ally with this feat, your **morale** bonuses to Strength and Constitution increase **by +4.**

Emphasis mine.  As this is increasing your already existing Morale bonus, these will be increased by 4 above the current amount.

Comment: I believe the reason for this wording is to make it also stack with [Greater Rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Greater-Rage-Ex-), for a total of +10, without having to directly distinguish the two cases.

Comment: ...And enjoy bookkeeping! Come prepared with your character sheet, your raging character sheet, your *enlarged* (you can do that, too, right?) character sheet, your raging *enlarged* character sheet, your flanking raging character sheet, your flanking *enlarged* raging character sheet...